# .htaccess mod_rewrite IP-based redirect: how to redirect all traffic to a specific subdirectory, except my IP?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want my visitors to have access only to a specific part of my website (blog). If they try to access other areas of the website, I'd like them redirected to the blog section.

I also want this to apply to everyone except to my IP address.

So the structure is as follows:

`mysite.com/blog  // visitor access allowed`

```
mysite.com        // redirect to mysite.com/blog

mysite.com/forum  // redirect to mysite.com/blog

mysite.com/tools  // redirect to mysite.com/blog

etc...
```

Do you have a suggestion on how to do this via .htaccess mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should be able to redirect with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^123\.456\.789
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /blog [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks @jordon - if I want to add more than one IP address, what would the syntax be?

Comment: @torr Just copy the first line to another line and keep adding them.

Comment: I think REMOTE_ADDR is preferable to REMOTE_HOST in order to get the IP address. REMOTE_HOST will not necessarily return the IP address if `HostnameLookups` is enabled (although this is Off by default).

Answer (score 3):

You should create a page that handles the specific redirects, and then edit your htaccess file to be something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
#not your IP
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^123\.123\.123\.123
#make sure the rule allows everyone to access the redirect page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/redirect_page\.html$
#Send them to the redirect page
RewriteRule \.html$ /redirect_page.html [R=302,L]
```

The rediret_page.html can have either js or server-side redirection that handles where they end up, but it will force everyone who has not come on your IP address through a specific page that handles redirection.

Comment: to clarify, I do not want my users to a redirect page - I want them to go to the front page of my blog (wordpress) which typically shows if I manually point the browser to `mysite.com/blog` -- does your code provide for this?

Comment: @torr: All you need to do is make the redirect page /blog then. I might recommend going through a PHP redirect page anyway, as it will give you better control, but it should work just using /blog

Answer (score 0):

Just add your IP Address in..

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from xxx.xx.xxx
```