# Block certain link on website for a specific IP range using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, block

There is a link for a video on my *PHP* page in our server. When particular user comes from a specific region, (assume from Latin America) video link will be displayed. But once user clicks on the link, I want to redirect the user to a forbidden page.

Can I do this using *.htaccess* file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit access based on certain file, use the following:

**Example:**

```
<Files wp-login.php>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from 139.82.0.0/16
</Files>
```

---

To be able to use geolocation and redirect a client based on country use [`mod_geoip2 Apache module`](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/mod_geoip2/):

**Example:**

```
GeoIPEnable On
GeoIPDBFile /path/to/GeoIP.dat

# Redirect one country
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^CA$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.canada.com$1 [R,L]

# Redirect multiple countries to a single page
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(CA|US|MX)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.northamerica.com$1 [R,L]
```

---

Another solution is to manually insert a list of IPs that would be blocked. There is online service called [**HTACCESS Block Country by IP Range**](http://incredibill.me/htaccess-block-country-ips) that would generate for you a list of IPs to block.

**Example:**

```
# BLOCK COUNTRY BY IP RANGE
# IncrediBILL's HTACCESS Tools
# http://incredibill.me
<Limit GET POST HEAD>
order allow,deny
#
# Block from BRAZIL (BR)
#
deny from 139.82.0.0/16
deny from 143.54.0.0/16
deny from 143.106.0.0/16
deny from 143.107.0.0/16
deny from 143.108.0.0/16
deny from 146.134.0.0/16
deny from 146.164.0.0/16
deny from 147.65.0.0/16
deny from 150.161.0.0/16
deny from 150.162.0.0/16
deny from 150.163.0.0/16
```

---

**One more possible and most appropriate solution for you, would be using *PHP* [`geoip module`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php), because you want to limit a user an access to certain parts of the page and doing it using *PHP* is much better.**

First of all, install [*php-pecl-geoip* module for PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/geoip.installation.php). Depending on your server configuration, installation is usually straight-forward. If you are using *RedHat/CentOS* simply run: `yum install php-pecl-geoip`. You must have root access to your server to install software, if you are using shared hosting, ask your administrator to do it for you.

After installation, you will have a whole new [set of PHP functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.geoip.php) available for you. The one you should use at the moment is `geoip_continent_code_by_name()`, as you asked to block all users from *South America*.

Applying it to your example is easy:

```
if ( geoip_continent_code_by_name( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ) == 'SA'  ) {
    echo '<a href="#">YouTube Video Example: This video is not available for South America.</a>';
} else {
    echo '<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoCode">YouTube Video Example</a>';
}
```

To test it on you server, you could just replace `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` with one of the IPs that belong to Brazil, e.g.: `geoip_continent_code_by_name('146.164.22.1');`

Comment: @llia, assume there is a index page.on that page there is href to a video on youtube.<a herf="www.youtube.com/abc">Video</a>.but when user comes from latin america and click on the link, i have to display that link os forbidden to you .how can i do that?

Comment: You should try it based on my example. If you can't I will come back in the evening to help you out. Got to go now!

Comment: i tried this but i couldn't find the correct method.if you can give a help.thanks

Comment: Have you install  `mod_geoip2` already? Do you have `mod_rewrite` enabled?

Comment: I provided you with another example with using `php-pecl-geoip` module.

Comment: @llia: ok will try that.thanks for your help.i think this will help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^123\.456\.789

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/?

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)$

RewriteRule (.*) /blog [R=301,L]
```

[.htaccess redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690480/htaccess-mod-rewrite-ip-based-redirect-how-to-redirect-all-traffic-to-a-specif)